# Multiple Orders in Sales Order Add request in qbxml

Tags: quickbooks, qbxml, ipp-qbd-sync

I am trying to add a sales order to quickbooks using Quickbooks Webconnector. When i add a single order its successfully added, but when i try to add multiple orders in a single qbxml, quickbooks throws the following error.

**"message="QuickBooks found an error when parsing the provided XML text stream."**

Following is the request QBXML sent

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<?qbxml version="8.0"?>
<QBXML>
    <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
        <SalesOrderAddRq>
            <SalesOrderAdd defMacro="MACROTYPE">
                <CustomerRef>
                    <FullName>Amazon.com.nvdc, Inc</FullName>
                </CustomerRef>
                <TxnDate>2014-07-29</TxnDate>
                <BillAddress>
                    <Addr1>RNO1</Addr1>
                    <City>Fernley</City>
                    <State>NV</State>
                    <PostalCode>89408-8903</PostalCode>
                    <Country>US</Country>
                </BillAddress>
                <PONumber>TST00003</PONumber>
                <DueDate>2014-07-29</DueDate>
                <SalesOrderLineAdd>
                    <ItemRef>
                        <FullName>ES-10BLU</FullName>
                    </ItemRef>
                    <Desc>ES-10BLU</Desc>
                    <Quantity>3</Quantity>
                    <UnitOfMeasure>EA</UnitOfMeasure>
                    <Rate>100.0</Rate>
                </SalesOrderLineAdd>
                <SalesOrderLineAdd>
                    <ItemRef>
                        <FullName>ES-10BLUINVALID</FullName>
                    </ItemRef>
                    <Desc>ES-10BLUINVALID</Desc>
                    <Quantity>4</Quantity>
                    <UnitOfMeasure>EA</UnitOfMeasure>
                    <Rate>100.0</Rate>
                </SalesOrderLineAdd>
                <SalesOrderLineAdd>
                    <ItemRef>
                        <FullName>ES-10BLUDISC</FullName>
                    </ItemRef>
                    <Desc>ES-10BLUDISC</Desc>
                    <Quantity>5</Quantity>
                    <UnitOfMeasure>EA</UnitOfMeasure>
                    <Rate>100.0</Rate>
                </SalesOrderLineAdd>
            </SalesOrderAdd>
            <SalesOrderAdd defMacro="MACROTYPE">
                <CustomerRef>
                    <FullName>Amazon.com.nvdc, Inc</FullName>
                </CustomerRef>
                <TxnDate>2014-07-29</TxnDate>
                <BillAddress>
                    <Addr1>RNO1</Addr1>
                    <City>Fernley</City>
                    <State>NV</State>
                    <PostalCode>89408-8903</PostalCode>
                    <Country>US</Country>
                </BillAddress>
                <PONumber>TST00004</PONumber>
                <DueDate>2014-07-29</DueDate>
                <SalesOrderLineAdd>
                    <ItemRef>
                        <FullName>ES-10BLU</FullName>
                    </ItemRef>
                    <Desc>ES-10BLU</Desc>
                    <Quantity>3</Quantity>
                    <UnitOfMeasure>EA</UnitOfMeasure>
                    <Rate>100.0</Rate>
                </SalesOrderLineAdd>
                <SalesOrderLineAdd>
                    <ItemRef>
                        <FullName>ES-10BLUINVALID</FullName>
                    </ItemRef>
                    <Desc>ES-10BLUINVALID</Desc>
                    <Quantity>4</Quantity>
                    <UnitOfMeasure>EA</UnitOfMeasure>
                    <Rate>100.0</Rate>
                </SalesOrderLineAdd>
                <SalesOrderLineAdd>
                    <ItemRef>
                        <FullName>ES-10BLUDISC</FullName>
                    </ItemRef>
                    <Desc>ES-10BLUDISC</Desc>
                    <Quantity>5</Quantity>
                    <UnitOfMeasure>EA</UnitOfMeasure>
                    <Rate>100.0</Rate>
                </SalesOrderLineAdd>
            </SalesOrderAdd>
            <SalesOrderAdd defMacro="MACROTYPE">
                <CustomerRef>
                    <FullName>Amazon.com.nvdc, Inc</FullName>
                </CustomerRef>
                <TxnDate>2014-07-29</TxnDate>
                <BillAddress>
                    <Addr1>RNO1</Addr1>
                    <City>Fernley</City>
                    <State>NV</State>
                    <PostalCode>89408-8903</PostalCode>
                    <Country>US</Country>
                </BillAddress>
                <PONumber>TST00005</PONumber>
                <DueDate>2014-07-29</DueDate>
                <SalesOrderLineAdd>
                    <ItemRef>
                        <FullName>ES-10BLU</FullName>
                    </ItemRef>
                    <Desc>ES-10BLU</Desc>
                    <Quantity>3</Quantity>
                    <UnitOfMeasure>EA</UnitOfMeasure>
                    <Rate>100.0</Rate>
                </SalesOrderLineAdd>
                <SalesOrderLineAdd>
                    <ItemRef>
                        <FullName>ES-10BLUINVALID</FullName>
                    </ItemRef>
                    <Desc>ES-10BLUINVALID</Desc>
                    <Quantity>4</Quantity>
                    <UnitOfMeasure>EA</UnitOfMeasure>
                    <Rate>100.0</Rate>
                </SalesOrderLineAdd>
                <SalesOrderLineAdd>
                    <ItemRef>
                        <FullName>ES-10BLUDISC</FullName>
                    </ItemRef>
                    <Desc>ES-10BLUDISC</Desc>
                    <Quantity>5</Quantity>
                    <UnitOfMeasure>EA</UnitOfMeasure>
                    <Rate>100.0</Rate>
                </SalesOrderLineAdd>
            </SalesOrderAdd>
        </SalesOrderAddRq>
    </QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
```

Does quickbooks support sending multiple sales orders in a single qbxml request or it accepts only one order in 1 request?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whenever you see this error message:

> QuickBooks found an error when parsing the provided XML text stream.

The very first thing you should be doing is running your XML through the *XML Validator* tool included with the *QuickBooks SDK*.

If you do that, you'll get this back:

```
Line: 48
LinePos: 49
Src Text: <SalesOrderAdd defMacro="MACROTYPE">
Reason: Element content is invalid according to the DTD/Schema.
Expecting: IncludeRetElement.
```

That's basically telling you that this tag:

```
<SalesOrderAdd
```

On this line:

```
Line: 48
```

Isn't correct.

It isn't correct because you didn't close your `</SalesOrderAddRq>` tag before opening a new `<SalesOrderAdd>` tag. You should have this around line 48 instead:

```
    </SalesOrderAdd>
</SalesOrderAddRq>  <!-- close the first request we're making... -->

<SalesOrderAddRq>  <!-- ... before starting our second request -->
    <SalesOrderAdd>
```